# Is Thermalization of a subsystem simply the result of Decoherence of its state?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information

I would appreciate answers that explain both the concepts in short to underline if there are any key differences between the two. Also, how does a localized state survive decoherence?

Comment: It is clear that the answer to this question will depend on ones understanding of the distinction between the classical and the quantum regimes of nature. An Everettian  might say that all classical process are quantum processes in disguise, but someone who subscribes to a spontaneous collapse theory would argue that there are genuine distinctions between the classical and the quantum. Although I think most people are relatively adamant about what they believe the correct answer is, there is bound to be strong disagreement on which answer is correct.